# Representing links to other entries in a database text column

Tags: database, database-design, content-management-system

I have a free text column in a database that needs to contain links to other  objects in the database, like definitions in an appendix. This database will feed a system like a CMS.

So far, I can only think of two ways of representing links in a free text field:

1. Markdown format: `[link](/entries/999)`
2. HTML

Am I missing any easier solutions?

Also, are there any ways to represent a link to entry 999 (for example) without hardcoding a URL? I want to generate the URLs automatically, and make the contents of the database resilient to changes in the way that the URLs are structured.

Maybe similar: [How to insert in a database elements with links to other elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346061/how-to-insert-in-a-database-elements-with-links-to-other-elements)

Comment: Do you need links to other table rows? Or to fields of table rows? Or to fragment of texts inside fields? And in which format are natively those text fields? HTML?

Comment: I want to have row-level links. In terms of a CMS, it would be like having a page link to another page, or a page link to an image. The text fields themselves would be in whatever markup format I need to support this linking.

Comment: So the link could be a couple primary key of row and name of field, something like this. This would make the SQL query more efficient. Then in you application you could translate this link in what is needed (html link, markdown link etc.). Or, maybe, you could store the links separately from the texts, in another table, with a couple of attributes start point of the link, end point of the link.

Comment: The devil is in the details with this problem, and I wanted to see some suggestions before reinventing the wheel. If you have a good idea, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that to solve a problem like this a couple of important points should be considered:

1. How important is the efficiency of the database queries (and this depends on the size of the database, on the frequency of the queries, on the load over the server, etc.)
2. What kind of updates are done to the data: is text (pages) modified frequently? These updates modify the links?

And another minor point is: how do you prefer to balance the work between the database server and the application, in terms of complexity of programming, performance, etc.

If I have understood your problem correctly (and I am not sure of this), there is always the need to translate “links” from the application level to the database level (otherwise you should not have particular problems). If this is true, then I think you have the following options:

1. Maintains the link with a “database semantics”: that is transform them in link to fields through a pair of values (primary key of record, name (or number) of field referred). Then, you have two sub-options: maintain those links inside the text, or extracting them in a (sub)table that contains the two end-points of the links (the starting point should be something like [key of record, name of field, position in the text where there is the link: the ending point could be simply [key of record, name of field]).
2. Leave a “text semantics” for the link, keeping them inside the text, and invent some kind of URL-like notation that can be easily converted into a database link or, alternatively, that could be used to perform effient searches in the database.

To evaluate which option to choose, than, one should consider the points above about the efficiency and the kind of updates.